# Android TabHost / back button

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a TabHost application with 4 tabs.

Tab 1 
List A > List B > View

Tab 2
Camera Activity which start camera and flash onCreate

Tab 3
List C > View

Tab 4
View D > View E

So, when I first start the app, I can go to different tabs back and forth the stack without any problem. But once I started Tab 2 (camera tab) and I go to other tabs from there and go down the stack and when i press the back button, the camera starts automatically even though I am not at Tab 2 (i.e.: at List B, press back button and camera starts even I just go back to List A) ...  and when I go to Tab 2 again, the app will crash (Sorry, the Android camera encountered a problem...etc.)

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?  Below is my TabHost activity

```
package com.myapp.appname;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.Window;


public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TabHost tabHost;
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.top_titlebar);
    setTabs();

}

private void setTabs() {
    tabHost = getTabHost();

    listTab(R.string.tab_1, R.drawable.ic_tab_1);
    cameraTab(R.string.tab_2, R.drawable.ic_tab_2);
    list2Tab(R.string.tab_3, R.drawable.ic_tab_3);
    viewTab(R.string.tab_4, R.drawable.ic_tab_4);
}

private void listTab(int labelId, int drawableId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ListActivity.class);    
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);     

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
private void cameraTab(int labelId, int drawableId) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,CameraActivity.class);  
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);     

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
private void list2Tab(int labelId, int drawableId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,List2Activity.class);   
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);     

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
private void viewTab(int labelId, int drawableId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ViewActivity.class);    
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);     

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the problem is with tabhost, but with camera. Try moving the code that you have in `onCreate` into `onResume`. Also you should worry about releasing the camera when you go to another tab.